# Running a Tor (non-exit) relay behind university firewall

Tags: relays, guard, middle

I have a personal laptop connected to a university connection, and reach the Internet through a proxy server. I have configured Tor to use only HTTP/HTTPS (since the firewall seems to reject all other connections as far as I'm aware).

Is it possible to run a non-exit relay under these circumstances? Is it possible for the network administrator to notice that I'm running a Tor relay? I understand that with deep packet inspection it's possible, but if they're just monitoring logs etc. can they figure it out?

I'm only asking because the admin has proven themselves to take very, very unkindly to any "hacking" that they see on the network, and using Tor is definitely in violation of the rules.

Comment: Are you suggesting running a Tor relay through a proxy?

Comment: @Cammy_the_block - Yup. Sorry, should have been clearer about that. Is it possible?

Comment: Just look at mirimir's answer, it explains everything I was going to say, but much more eloquently.

Comment: Is the proxy you are referring to **required** for access to the internet?

Comment: @Spooky - Yup. It blocks everything that isn't http/https (AFAIK). And we *have* to configure the web browser to use this proxy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if you got this to work, it wouldn't benefit the Tor network. Proxies tend to be slow and unreliable, so your relay would be as well.

Also, a Tor relay wouldn't go unnoticed for very long. Few students are online 24/7, as the relay (with luck) would be. And given your comment about the admin, you would soon be in trouble.

You could use your own private proxy. However, it would be better and safer to just run the relay remotely.